# How to override ToString() for ExpandoObject in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

The `ExpandoObject` is **sealed**, can't be inherited directly.

**EDIT2**: Why I use the `ExpandoObject` not `DynamicObject`, because the `ExpandoObject` implemented **`INotifyPropertyChanged`**, which supported in WPF. And in wpf, the Control will call implicit ToString mentioned of `System.Object`, so is it possible to override `System.Object.ToString()` for **`ExpandoObject`** ?

Thanks and sorry for @Los Frijoles, I havn't express my question well before.

Comment: What do you meant by *But this will lost the feeling of "dynamic"*?

Comment: If I have 10 diff kinds of instance, and every kind ToString() may need diff implementing, So I need to creat 10 subclass? @Sriram Sakthivel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about "elegant", but you could always try this:

```
public delegate string ToStringFunc();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic test = new ExpandoObject();

    test.ToString = new ToStringFunc(() =>
        {
            return "Test";
        });

    Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
}
```

This simply creates a value called `ToString` which happens to be a function delegate which looks like the normal method signature for a `ToString` function.

This avoids needing to extend `ExpandoObject` or the like and seems to maintain what I would think of as the "dynamic" feel of being able to define how an object "appears" at run-time only. Of course, what exactly "dynamic feel" means is totally subjective.

**EDIT**:

Here is a version that will allow for the implicit ToString mentioned in the comments using `DynamicObject` but still allowing for a portion of the "Expando" capability given by `ExpandoObject`: https://gist.github.com/kcuzner/3670e78ae1707a0e959d

It's beyond the scope of what the author asked for, but I figured I would include it for those viewing this answer later.

Comment: Is it implicitly called if you print the object?

Comment: No. If the object is cast to `System.Object` (which is what happens when its simply printed), the `ToString` method native to `ExpandoObject` will be executed instead of performing the property lookup and getting back our new method delegate. By explicitly calling `ToString` on something the compiler knew was a `dynamic` it performed the property lookup first. If you wanted that to work implicitly I would guess (and it's a guess) that one would need to override `ToString` in a subclass and I don't see a way around that. I haven't played around enough with `dynamic` to know the intricacies.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is working, and I made a mistake: the `ExpandoObject` is **sealed**, can't be extended. PS: we also can change the delegate of ToStringFunc to `Func<string>()`

Comment: `DyamicObject` can be extended and is the class you want to use if you go the extension route.

Comment: No. I need `ExpandoObject`, cz it implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`